# HTML using RAZOR to pull data from database

Tags: html, sql, razor

The code below belongs to my `Details.cshtml` page.

Everything it working fine however when trying to get the details for a `Card` the data isn't pulled and returns empty.

```
<p>Card ID: @cardId</p>
<p>Data: @cardId</p>
<p>Data Exists: @(cardId != null)</p>
```

Returns fine in the first instance.

```
<p>Card ID: @cardId</p>
<p>Data: @data</p>
<p>Data Exists: @(data != null)</p>
```

Returns:

Card ID: 22908

Data:

Data Exists: False

I have run the SQL queries in the database directly and it returns the data fine.
Any help would be muchly appreciated thank you.

```
@using WebMatrix.Data;

@{
    var db = Database.Open("MTGDecks");

    //Grab all the cards info
    var sqlCardId = "SELECT cardID FROM Cards Where cardID = @0";
    var cardId = db.QueryValue(sqlCardId, Request.QueryString["cardId"]);

    <p>Card ID: @cardId</p>
    <p>Data: @cardId</p>
    <p>Data Exists: @(cardId != null)</p>

    //Get the users so we can add cards into the decks
    // var db = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE userID = 0"

    var detailsSql = "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Cards AS C " +
                    "JOIN Artists AS A ON A.artistID = C.artistID " +
                    "JOIN CardStats AS CS ON CS.cardID = C.cardID " +
                    "JOIN CardHasKeywords as CHK on CHK.cardID = C.cardID " +
                    "JOIN Keywords AS K ON K.Keyword = CHK.Keyword " +
                    "JOIN CardHasTypes AS CHT ON CHT.cardID = C.cardID " +
                    "JOIN CardTypes AS CT ON CT.cardType = CHT.cardType " +
                    "JOIN FlavourTexts AS FT ON FT.cardID = C.cardID " +
                    "JOIN CardManaCosts AS CMC ON CMC.cardID = C.cardID " +
                    "WHERE C.cardID = @0";

    var data = db.QuerySingle(detailsSql, cardId);

    <p>Card ID: @cardId</p>
    <p>Data: @data</p>
    <p>Data Exists: @(data != null)</p>

}
```